# Palindrome using NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, palindrome

I wrote a code for finding palindrome. But my code shows output "is not pallindrome" for all the cases. My program is given following:

```
section .data
    a db "mommom",0
    b equ $-a

    msg1 db "is pallindrome",10,0
    msg2 db "is not pallindrome",10,0
    msg3 db "",10,0
section .text
    global main
    extern printf
main:
    nop
    xor eax,eax
    xor ebx,ebx
    mov eax,a       ;starting add
    mov ebx,b
    add eax,ebx
    dec eax         ;will use to indicate the last letter of a

    xor ebx,ebx
    xor edx,edx
    xor ecx,ecx

start:
    inc ecx
    cmp ecx,(b/2)       ;check will run for half of the word
    jle check
    jmp pal
check:  
    mov dl,byte[eax]    ;last letter
    cmp byte[a+ebx],dl  ;frst letter compares with last letter
debug:
    pusha           ;debugging purpose.Used to catch the first letter of a
    push byte[a+ebx]
    push msg3
    call printf
    add esp,8
    popa
checkContinue:
    inc ebx         ;use for check segment
    dec eax
    je start
    jne nonPal
pal:
    pusha
    push msg1
    call printf
    add esp,4
    popa
    jmp done
nonPal:
    pusha
    push msg2
    call printf
    add esp,4
    popa
    jmp done
done:
     nop
```

Antoine Mathys has already given us the appropriate version of the above code pointing out the mistakes have occurred in this code. His remarks section is very important for us like newbie. Here, in this above program, I tried to print every character residing in the ebx register and I failed to get that. I will be grateful if any mentor can approach this portion of the problem. It will help me to learn how to take each character from a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
        BITS 32
        section .data
        string db "mommom"
        length equ $ - string

        msg1 db "is pallindrome",0
        msg2 db "is not pallindrome",0

        section .text
        global main
        extern puts

main:
        mov ebx, string                   ; start of word                                 
        mov eax, (string + length - 1)    ; end of word                                   

        mov ecx, (length / 2)             ; check will run for half of the word           
check:
        mov dl, [ebx]                     ; compare first and last letters                
        cmp [eax], dl
        jne failure
        inc ebx
        dec eax
        loop check

        ;; success                                                                  
        push msg1
        call puts
        add esp,4
        jmp done

failure:
        push msg2
        call puts
        add esp,4

done:
        ret
```

Some remarks:

- Don't add a zero to the word to test. That would make it a non-palindrome.
- Your code was full of unnecessary instructions (pusha/popa, nop, clearing edx but only using dl, ...). Try to keep the code as simple as possible.
- Don't use the xor trick, write for clarity
- Use meaningful symbol names
- Take advantage of assembler arithmetic expressions

Comment: "`xor` trick", as you say, is the common practice. I don't consider it as a "trick", for me `xor reg,reg` is synonymous with zeroing the register in question, and rather `mov ecx,0` makes me think there is some reason why **not** to modify the flags, as `xor reg,reg` is the standard practice. Also, `xor ecx,ecx` takes only 2 bytes, whereas `mov ecx,0` takes 5 bytes.

Comment: @Antonie Mathys:thank you very much.You make clear few of my confusions. Yet, I just appreciate your advice if you tell me how do I print a character which I tried to print in purpose of debugging in my earlier code. Again, thank you. I had not the idea to operate with character clearly

Comment: @Antonie Mathys: My class teacher has showed me to follow this format of using nop at the beginning and the end and using pusha/popa in the time of printing

Comment: @Antoine Mathys: can you please follow my another question which I have asked here?I beg apology to bother you on this cases

Answer (score 0):

I keep seeing these palindrome questions with clunky code from beginners, which got me interested in writing a version that's actually efficient.  My byte-at-a-time loop should run at one iteration per clock on Intel Haswell, but slower on earlier Intel (because the loop will be more than 4 fused-domain uops because of limited macro-fusion for back-to-back cmp/jcc).

Also see below for a way to make it case-insensitive.

---

**Checking more than one byte at a time works, even with overlap at the crossover in the middle**:

```
 abcdcba
 abcd
    dcba    ; overlap by one
  bcdc
   cdcb     ; overlap by two
```

Load some bytes, reverse the order with `bswap`, Silvermont/Haswell `movbe`, SSSE3 `pshufb`, or even `rol ax,8`/`rol eax,16`/`rol ax,8`.  Then compare with the same number of bytes where there should be a match.

---

Add in printing of results however you like.  I just return an exit status.

All of this works the same in 32bit, but I used 64bit because the register calling convention avoids cluttering in the code with stack manipulation.

Note the use of local labels (`.label`) to avoid conflicts between similar blocks of code that use the same label names.

```
DEFAULT rel
section .text

ALIGN 16
global check_palindrome
                   ; AMD64 SysV calling convention
check_palindrome:  ; (size_t len /*rdi*/, const char *str /*rsi*/)
;;returns bool
    cmp    rdi, 8
    jb   check_palindrome_byte_at_a_time      ; tailcall the version that handles small inputs
    add    rdi, rsi      ; rdi = end pointer
;ALIGN 16  ; probably not worth it, depending on the CPU
.palin_loop:
    lodsq                ; rax = [rsi], rsi+=8.  lodsd/q is only 2 uops on Haswell
    bswap  rax
    sub    rdi, 8
    cmp    rax, [rdi]
    jne  .not_palin
    cmp    rsi, rdi
    jb   .palin_loop          ; stop looping when the pointers cross
    ;; Loop has 7 uops on Haswell, so it can sustain one iteration (8 bytes in each direction) per 2 cycles.
    ;; 9 uops on SnB, where lodsq is 3 uops, and only one of cmp/jcc pairs can macro-fuse.  For SnB, use mov / add instead of lodsq
    ;; with unrolling, we might get this down closer to 2x8B per clock, instead of per 2 clocks.
    ;; or with SSE/AVX, 2x16B per clock.  Probably not 2x32B per clock with AVX, due to needing two shuffles.  (no cross-lane byte shuffle until AVX512)

; input was a palindrome
    mov    eax, 1             ; return true
    ret

.not_palin:
    xor    eax,eax            ; return false
    ret

ALIGN 16
;; helper function with the same signature as the main version
; only needed for small strings, not for unaligned, or not-multiple-of-8
    ; assume that rdi < 2^32 so we can use edi interchangeably, for smaller code-size.
    ; If our prototype was (unsigned int, const char*), we'd have to mov ecx, edi  or something.
    ;  (moving to a different reg is preferable to mov edi,edi  because mov-elimination never works on mov same,same)
check_palindrome_byte_at_a_time:
    cmp   edi, 1
    jbe  .is_palin          ; the empty string is a palindrome, as is length 1

;ALIGN 16
.palin_loop:                   ; do{
    movzx  eax, byte ptr [rsi + rdi - 1] ; 2-register addresses can't micro-fuse on SnB-family, but this is a pure load that doesn't need to micro-fuse with anything.  MOVZX avoids false dependencies and extra merging uops on CPUs that don't rename AL separate from EAX; it would need to micro-fuse on Haswell if we'd used mov al, [mem]
    cmp    al, [rsi]
    jne  check_palindrome.not_palin
    inc    rsi                 ; pointer moves forward
    sub    edi, 2              ; index counts down towards zero twice as fast
    ja   .palin_loop           ; }while((idx-=2) > 0U);  Ideally would leave the loop on EDI==1 as well, as any byte equals itself
;;; Haswell and later can fuse both branches even when they hit the decoders in the same cycle
;;; so this loop should hopefully be 4 fused-domain uops and run at one iteration per clock

.is_palin:
    mov    eax, 1             ; return true
    ret
; .not_palin:  ; shared code with other check_palindrome version



    global main
    extern strlen
ALIGN 16
main:
    ;; return !check_palindrome(strlen(argv[1]), argv[1])

    ;mov    edi, inputstr_len
    ;mov    esi, inputstr
    mov    rdi, [rsi+8]       ; argv[1]
    push   rdi                ; save it, and align the stack
    call   strlen
    mov    rdi, rax
    mov    rsi, [rsp]         ; could pop here and take advantage of the fact that we know check_palindrome doesn't care about the stack
    call   check_palindrome
    pop    rdi                ; shorter than  add rsp,8  and faster on Intel CPUs with a stack engine, given the surrounding instructions
    xor    eax, 1             ; we know check_palin returns a _Bool, so flip it
    ret


;;; Unused, but improved in case you do want to use it
section .rodata
    inputstr    db "mommom"
    inputstr_len equ $-inputstr

    msg_palin   db "is palindrome",10,0
    msg_nopalin db "is not palindrome"   ; newline an terminating zero are on the next line, with their own label
    msg_newline db 10,0
```

(inspiration for how to write some of `main()` from [gcc output on godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:%27-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dhaswell%27,source:%27int+f(int+x)+%7B+return+!!x%3B+%7D%0A_Bool+fbool(_Bool+x)+%7B+return+!!x%3B+%7D%0A%0A/*int+main(int+argc,+char**argv)+%7B%0A++return+puts(argv%5B1%5D)%3B%0A%7D%0A*/%0A%23include+%3Cstring.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdbool.h%3E%0A%0Abool+check_palindrome(unsigned+long+len,+const+char*str)%3B%0Aint+main(int+argc,char**argv)%7B%0A++return+!!check_palindrome(strlen(argv%5B1%5D),+argv%5B1%5D)%3B%0A%7D%27)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3).  Compiler output is often a good starting point.)

---

#### Tested and works:

```
$ yasm -Worphan-labels -gdwarf2 -felf64 palindrome.asm && gcc palindrome.o -o palindrome

$ ./palindrome '' && echo "true" || echo "false"
true
$ ./palindrome 1 && echo "true" || echo false
true
$ ./palindrome abccba && echo "true" || echo "false"
true          # even size: pair of middle chars
$ ./palindrome abcdcba && echo "true" || echo "false"
true          # odd size: single middle char
$ ./palindrome abcdeba && echo "true" || echo "false"
false

$ ./palindrome 'ab bcdcb 1234 bcdcb baab bcdcb 4321 bcdcb ba' && echo "true" || echo "false"
true
$ ./palindrome 'ab bcdcb 1234 bcdcb bab bcdcb 4321 bcdcb ba' && echo "true" || echo "false"
true
$ ./palindrome 'ab bcdcb 1234 bcdcb baab bcdcb 4321 bcdcb baa' && echo "true" || echo "false"
false

$ ./palindrome && echo "true" || echo "false"
Segmentation fault (core dumped)   # main doesn't check argc
```

---

#### Case-insensitive:

As well as byte-reversing one chunk, force the alphabetic characters of both chunks to lower case before comparing.  With ASCII, [this is easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936844/224132).  That answer I linked even has an SSE vector implementation of case-flipping, which can be modified to just force all alphabetic characters to the same case (either replace the final `pxor` with `por`, or use a blend with the compare result as the control, instead of `pandn`/`por`.)

---

#### Unrolling:

As well as using displacements (`[rsi+8]`, `[rdi-8]`, etc) to save add/sub instructions, you can reduce the number of branches by ORing or ANDing some compare results together.  This may or may not save anything.  On a CPU that doesn't suffer from [partial-register merging slowdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers) at all (e.g. AMD), this might be a win:

```
.palin_loop:
    xor   eax,eax   ; inside the loop to break the false dependency
    xor   edx,edx

    movbe  ... / cmp   ...       ; movbe is a load and endian swap in one insn.  On Haswell it just saves code-size, not uops.  On Silvermont it's a win
    setne  dl
    movbe  rcx, [rsi+rdi-16] / cmp  [rsi+8], rcx
    setne  dh
    shl    edx, 16    ; DH merging takes a cycle on Haswell
    ... repeat setting dl/dh so edx holds 4 results from four 8B checks

    movbe ... / cmp   ...
    setne  al
    movbe ... / cmp   ...
    setne  ah
    shl    eax, 16
    ... repeat setting al/ah
    
    or    eax, edx             ; or unroll twice as much, and use rax,rdx
    jnz  .not_palin
```

Perhaps a better strategy would be to `or` some `xor` results, like

```
  movbe  rdx, [rsi+rdi-8]
  xor    rdx, [rsi+8]      ; all-zero if they match, otherwise not
  movbe  rcx, [rsi+rdi-16]
  xor    rcx, [rsi+8]

  or     rcx, rdx       ; ZF=0 if there are any mismatches in either XOR result
```

With SSE, where compare results already are boolean 0/-1 elements, you can `pand` to check that every element matched in both `pcmpeqb` results.  Then one `pmovmskb` / `cmp eax, 0xffff` at the end can check multiple vectors of compare results.  (See glibc `memcmp` and `strlen` unrolled loops for this and other tricks.)

---

#### AVX:

It looks like the loop structure from the byte-at-a-time version is idea,
and we use pshufb to reverse the order of a whole vector.  The `pmovmskb` and testing the bitmask is a pretty standard idiom for dealing with vector-compare results.  It's faster than `PTEST`, because `PTEST` is 2 uops and can't macro-fuse.

```
DEFAULT rel

section .rodata
ALIGN 16
bytereverse_shuffle db 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0

section .text

ALIGN 16
global check_palindrome_AVX1
check_palindrome_AVX1:
    cmp         rdi, 32
    jb        check_palindrome_byte_at_a_time   ; tailcall the version that handles small inputs

    vmovdqa    xmm5, [bytereverse_shuffle]

;;ALIGN 16 ; NASM syntax doesn't have an equivalent for the GNU assembler's align-if-padding-will-be-less-than-N-bytes .p2align 4,,8   (4 meaning 2^4 for power-of-2 align)
;; loop alignment is less important for tiny loops that should fit in the loop buffer

.palin_loop:
    vmovdqu     xmm0, [rsi + rdi - 16]
    vpshufb     xmm0, xmm0, xmm5  ; bswap
;;; for AVX2 ymm:   vperm2i128 ymm0, ymm0, ymm0, 1  ; swap hi and lo lanes
    vpcmpeqb    xmm0, xmm0, [rsi] ; all we're gaining from AVX is folding this potentially-unaligned memory operand.  Everything else works with SSE
    vpmovmskb   eax, xmm0
    cmp         eax, 0xffff     ; check that all 16bits are set -> all 16bytes matched
    jne       .not_palin
    add         rsi, 16         ; pointer moves forward
    sub         rdi, 32         ; index counts down towards zero twice as fast
    jae       .palin_loop       ; not ja: we still need to check 16 reversed bytes against the same 16 bytes if we exactly meet in the middle
;;; fused-domain uops: 7 for Haswell, 8 for SnB, so it should run one iteration per 2c
;;; An SSSE3 version that needs an unaligned load separate from pcmpeq will be 8 uops (or 9 on pre-Haswell)

.is_palin:
    mov         eax, 1
    ret
.not_palin:
    xor         eax,eax
    ret
```